# Html.Action link returns 404 error after deployment

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to call a action from a controller on click of actionlink. It works perfect in my local but it doesn't work after deployment (results 404 Error). Please someone help on this.

View:

```
<%:Html.ActionLink("Activate", "RepresentativeAccessActivate","AdminNew", new { id = uselist.email_user_name }, new { onclick = "return confirm('Are you sure you want to activate this user?')" ,@class="view"}) %>
```

Action :

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult RepresentativeAccessActivate(string id)
    {
        FramesBusinessService.FramesBusinessSeviceClient client = new FramesBusinessService.FramesBusinessSeviceClient();
        client.Ser_UpdateRepresentativeStatus(id, true, "salesrepresentative");
        client.Close();
        return RedirectToAction("Representative");
    }
```

Comment: Try to check your steps with breakpoints.. And why do you use HttpGet ??

Comment: Can you try to access directly yo this action ? I think you will get he 404 error too. Its a ell known server config error

Comment: what is the correct way to do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.Net MVC2 Controller Path not found IIS7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17994394/asp-net-mvc2-controller-path-not-found-iis7)