# ASP.Net MVC2 Controller Path not found IIS7

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC2 application hosted in IIS7(integrated pool). The link that I use to access the application is like this

```
http://88.88.88.88/testapp/
```

I am invoking the PrintApp function from my 'HomeController.cs' as shown below.

```
var printForm = jQuery('<form>', {
    'method' : 'post',
    'action' : 'Home/PrintApp'
     .....});
printForm .submit();
```

This thing works when I use it with visual studio developement server. But when deployed on IIS, it gives me 404 error.

I tried,

```
'action' : '../Home/PrintApp'
```

But this also gives me the same error. The only thing that worked was

```
'action' : 'http://88.88.88.88/testapp/Home/PrintApp'
```

which is not the best way to do it..Can someone identify what the issue is?

Comment: try '~/Home/PrintApp'

Comment: @JeevanJose - does that work inside .js files?i will try..

Comment: it works now..not sure what it was..i changed the application pool to classic and then back to integrated..might be something else..

Answer (score 2):

You wrote the following javascript code inside some event which is triggered upon interaction with some DOM element such as a button or an anchor, right?

such as:

```
$('#foobar').click(function() {
    var printForm = jQuery('<form>', {
        'method' : 'post',
        'action' : 'Home/PrintApp'
        .......
    });
    printForm.submit();
});
```

so, you could add the url of the form as `data-*` attribute to the corresponding element:

```
<button id="foobar" data-url="@Url.Action("PrintApp", "Home")">Click me</button>
```

and then:

```
$('#foobar').click(function() {

    var printForm = jQuery('<form>', {
        'method' : 'post',
        'action' : $(this).data(url)
        .......
    });
    printForm.submit();

});
```

Answer (score 1):

If the JavaScript is being called from within a View, you can use this instead (this assumes Razor view engine...for ASPX, it will be slightly different):

```
var printForm = jQuery('<form>', {
    'method' : 'post',
    'action' : '@Url.Action("PrintApp", "Home")'
     .....});
printForm .submit();
```

If it is being called from elsewhere, you will have to provide a fully-qualified reference to the location of your controller action.

EDIT:  Would something like this work?

In the .js:

```
function submitPrintForm(formLocation) {
    var printForm = jQuery('<form>', {
        'method' : 'post',
        'action' : formLocation
         .....});
    printForm .submit();
}
```

In the View, wherever you need to call the function:

```
submitPrintForm('@Url.Action("PrintApp", "Home")';
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this line `'action' : 'Home/PrintApp'`, to this:

```
'action' : $('#printAppUrl').val();
```

Then, server-side in the view, set the value of a hidden field named `printAppUrl` to this:

```
@Html.Hidden("printAppUrl", Url.Action("PrintApp", "Home"));
```

Another thing to try is this:

```
'/Home/PrintApp'
```

I say that because after generating a form myself in a test application that's what the URL looked like.

Comment: It will definitely work, and I almost upvoted it, but it just feels like a "dirty" solution.

Comment: @vinayan, you could also try `'/Home/PrintApp'`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is absolute and relative paths. One of these should work for you:

```
var printForm = jQuery('<form>', {
'method' : 'post',
'action' : '~/Home/PrintApp'
 .....});
printForm .submit();
```

OR

```
var printForm = jQuery('<form>', {
'method' : 'post',
'action' : '../../Home/PrintApp'
 .....});
printForm .submit();
```